# SSMS And Visual Basic Express .... cannot backup

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Let us start with...yes I am new to SQL and really only a lightweight programmer. So I am assuming that I am doing something horribly wrong. I have spent days on the MS forums looking for an answer to no avail. So I am going to give as much info as possible.

Application language is VBExpress 2010 and using SQLExpress 2008. The Database contain basic tables, no stored procs, no views, no diagrams. The Application has configured diagrams where one of the tables has inner joins... Tables origninally built in SSMS, but have been altered in VBE.

Anytime I run the application, even after exiting the application, if I then go to SSMS I can see the database name but I cannot open it up (no + beside it). If I try I get an error that says:

One or more files do not match the primary file of the database. If you are attempting to attach a database retry the operation with the correct files.  If this is an existing database the file may be corrupted and should be restored from a backup."

When I look at the files, I see two log files, one with _1 appended on to it. If I delete the logfiles before opening SSMS, everything opens fine. If I had already opened SSMS then I have to delete the files, reboot my computer and then I can access the database through SSMS...

I recently found that if I go into SSMS, take the database offline and then bring it back online I can get access back.

Anytime I open SSMS, I have to completely reboot my computer before VBE will reconnect the database.

The bottom line is that I cannot back up the database without either deleting the log files or doing an offline/online cycle in SSMS....

This is driving me nuts. I cannot possilby deploy the application if I cannot achieve a normal backup procedure. And I cannot seem to get any kind of answer about why this is happening.

What am I doing so WRONG?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 then, reattach the database files and it will must be stored in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL 10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA. 
And recheck the database on that folder and it will take backup and restore point of Primary files of Database. Don't modify/delete the database files. If the location of log files are changed the it will shows the error. Please give your mail id I'll send a program to restore and backup of database files in winrar.

Thank you

Regards,
Naresh.

Comment: Thanks Naresh, You gave me the final clue that I needed... Using VBE to change the structure of the Database is a bad idea. When you do use VBE designer, it generates a Second logfile with a _1 appended to it. This upsets SSMS and SQL server.....not so much that your program will not run, but enough that you cannot get back into SSMS or do a backup. But all is not lost. Get out of VBE, delete the logfiles and you are good to go..... Thanks again.